# Minimal number of clues required to uniquely determine a Latin Square

Tags: computational-mathematics, latin-square

[image]

Let's suppose I want to fill a n*n array with numbers occuring from 1 to n. One number is allowed to appear only once in every column/row. The solution becomes unique when there is only one possible way to complete the puzzle. I'm looking for the smallest number of clues(initially specified elements) to uniquely determine the solution in the function of n.

Example: For a 3x3 matrix this number is 2, since

1 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 0

by the set of instruction I provided above can be completed in only one way.

Comment: Are you asking about completing a Latin square?  The only mention of a Latin square is in the title,  Please use the body of your Question to give an exact statement of the problem you want help with, and then add context (such as any upper bound on the number of squares needed for uniqueness that you worked out by examples).

Comment: I assume you clearly understood the problem.

Comment: There is research on this problem in the literature.  See this 2006 paper "On the size of the minimum critical set of a Latin square" by [Ghandehari, Hatami, and Mahmoodian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701015.pdf), citing earlier work by Cavenagh (in a 2003 Ph.D. thesis).  I don't know any exact result for the general size $n$.

Comment: A survey of earlier work can be found in Keedwell (2001) "Critical Sets in Latin Squares: An Intriguing Problem" The Mathematical Gazette ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3622009)).

Comment: See also the comment by Richard Bean on [OEIS Sequence A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620).